# Magento 2Checkout currency issue

Tags: magento, 2checkout

I have a problem with passing amount to 2Checkout payment page. If some other currency is selected on Magento front end, the amount that is passed to 2Checkout payment page is converted amount. 2Checkout has its own currency converter so if user wants to pay with some other currency he is able to convert it on 2Checkout payment page, but in this case he will convert converted amount not Base currency amount from Magento front end.
I was wandering how to fix this issue, or how can i edit 2Checkout extension files to pass default currency amount to 2Checkout payment page instead of passing converted one???

THNX!

Answer (score 0):

This has already been implemented in the latest version of the extension so all you need to do is uninstall your extension from Magento Connect in your admin and reinstall from the URL below:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/2checkout-payment-extension.html

Now if you list in multiple currencies, it will show the customer currency amount and show them that they will be charged the base amount in your default pricing currency. This total is then passed to 2Checkout.

I added this change in back in July because of a bunch of requests from the community and thus far everyone seems happy with it. Please feel free to contact me to let me know if you have any questions or concerns so I can assist with your 2Checkout integration.

Comment: Ok.I'll try with this. Thnx Alot!